# PyQt Dock Widgets

Tags: pyqt, qdockwidget

I have a main window (`QMainWindow`) containing a dock-able section (`QDockWidget`). The dock-able section can be torn off and used as a floating window. I would like to be able to allow the user to tear off the dock-able section, close the main window and continue to use the dock-able section as a standalone thing. I assume my design is part of the problem so I should explain the purpose of the GUI.

Basically the main window is used to create processes that perform various tasks. Each time a process (`QThread`) is created it is displayed in the dock-able section. Once the user has finished creating processes he/she is finished with the main window but may want to keep the dock-able section open as many of the processes could still be waiting in a queue. Make sense? If so, how can I close the main window without closing the dock-able section? Or am I trying to go about this the wrong way?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the dock section in your layout is a child of main window, so if you're closing\hiding main window, it's children will be hidden\destroyed. Maybe you should spawn a new completely separate and independent window and use that?